# Page not getting aligned when width set dynamically in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a hamburger menu(show/hide) in left panel. When I open the menu, the right content width is set dynamically, so when I set the width of the content in the container it is not aligned properly (right aligning - not centered, as expected) and if I open the inspect element window, then the container is properly aligned as expected (center aligned).

my code is:

```
$( ".off-canvas__container.off-canvas__content" )
   .width($( ".off-canvas__container.off-canvas__content" ).width()+250);
```

Comment: would you provide us the codes

Comment: $( ".off-canvas__container.off-canvas__content" ).width($( ".off-canvas__container.off-canvas__content" ).width()+250);

Comment: a little html too and edit your question

Comment: if I may ask, why does this question have an angularjs tag?